# libsvm: how to suppress display

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I'm using libsvm for MATLAB. Does anybody know how to suppress the screen display "optimization finished, iter = 8 nu =..." ? I think I've already described the question properly, but for some reason stack overflow won't let me post this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's faq contains the answers:

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f417

EDIT:

There is the `-q` option in the matlab interface to make it quiet.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I searched for all files in the libsvm folder but didn't find  "optimization finished,...", so I don't know to which files should the lines be added.

Comment: The link I pasted tells the general approach depending on whether you use libsvm in commandline or as a C++ library. In your case you are using it under MATLAB, so to follow the instructions in the faq you will need to open the .c files under the matlab directory and do the corresponding thing. However, I just checked the matlab directory and in the instruction (contained in the string help messages in svmtrain.c), it gives you an option (the -q option) to make it quiet.

Comment: To answer your question, the string is contained in "svm.cpp" at line 774. But I don't think it's a good idea to modify the code in this way.